# How to plot GPS coordinates in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, gps, nmea

**Question: How do I plot GPS longitude and Latitude coordinates using the scatter or geoshow function (or whatever function works best)**

Hi everyone

I have this GPS unit I'd like to analyze so I went out and tested it, got several pages of NMEA sentences (for 3 different spots on the same field) that I like to plot using Matlab's scatter function (or geoshow function...whatever works).

Since NMEA sentences give out tons of information which I don't need; I sorted through and simplified the data to contain only longitude in one file and latitude in another file (I have several spots locations).

I made both files .csv files so I could read in these files using Matlab's csvread function rather than having to manually enter these numbers manually into matrices.

The problem I have is that when I go to plot these spots I can only show 1 spot on 1 graph at a time. This really defeats the purpose of graphing the coordinates...how can I graph all 3 spots all on the same graph using the .csv files I made or any method you know of?

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
 SW_latitude = csvread('SW_latitude.csv'); 
 SW_longitude = csvread('SW_longitude.csv');

 CENTER_latitude = csvread('center_latitude.csv'); 
 CENTER_longitude = csvread('center_longitude.csv');

 WALKING_latitude = csvread('WALKING_latitude.csv'); 
 WALKING_longitude = csvread('WALKING_longitude.csv');
 scatter(SW_latitude,SW_longitude) 
 hold on
 scatter(CENTER_latitude,CENTER_longitude)
 scatter(WALKING_latitude,WALKING_longitude)
 hold off
```

[image: Screen shot of one coordinate being plotted...why only just 1 dot? I should see a scatter?]

Comment: It looks like you have at least two spots on that figure, but some of them are at zero.  What are the ranges of your various latitude/longitude measurements? Given the apparent range, you might also want to convert to decimal degrees (i.e for some NMEA, you might have values like 11122.33 which means 111 degrees, 22.33 minutes).

Comment: How do I do this? I loaded all the longitude values into a longitude.csv file and all the latitude values into a latitude.csv file...Should I go in and manually separate the values, if so what format should I edit them? I inputted a zero at the beginning of every file, just to make sure it was being plotted correctly, I will remove the zero

Comment: Also, try `hold all` so you don't get all 3 plots in the same colour.

Comment: This is the range for the longitude.csv file: 3246.4270 - 3246.4280 and this is the range for latitude.csv file: 11704.3785,- 11704.3400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) NMEA messages often have the longitude and latitude of the format 3246.4270, 11704.3785 etc.

The two numerals before the decimal point and those after are minutes, the two/three numerals at the front are degrees, i.e. 32 degrees, 46.4270 minutes, 117 degrees, 04.3785 minutes, etc.  You can convert these to decimal degrees after loading (doesn't need three lines but hopefully this makes the process clearer):

```
degrees = floor(lat/100); % number of degrees
minutes = lat-degrees*100; % number of minutes
lat2 = degrees + minutes/60;
```

2) If your values are all from within a small area, the changes in latitude and longitude will not be great. Therefore, watch your axis limits.  You can set these with `xlim` and `ylim` after plotting if you know the approximate range you want to examine.

3) There is a free mapping toolbox, [m_map](http://www2.ocgy.ubc.ca/~rich/map.html), which I quite like.  Otherwise, if using `geoshow` you may have to set the display type to `Point`.  You can set the various color/marker settings as well.  Take a handle when you plot and then use `get` and `set` to check what sort of settings you can adjust.

```
h = geoshow(lat, lon, 'DisplayType', 'Point')
```

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested and the data now is formatted correct but I am having the same trouble, one one data point is plotted even after    **hold all**

Comment: What happens if you just plot one set of your lat and lon, and what are the axis limits? You may need to rescale/zoom in to see your data properly. If you keep getting points at (0,0), you won't be able to see the very small variation in your real lat/lon which is only a fraction of a degree.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong...I had separate files for each waypoint so I had 6 separate files for 3 waypoints(lat and lon for each waypoint), I included all the latitude and longitude data in 2 separate csv files. Now using the conversion algorithm you created, I was able to plot all 3 waypoints. Thank you